# Get the text after characters in a string in applescript

Tags: string, macos, text, applescript, character

I have some files that have some text, 50 newlines (don't ask), and then some more text.  How can I get just the text after the newlines?  Shell scripts are fine.  Any answer would be appreciated, as I've been stuck on this for a while.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
set input to read POSIX file "/tmp/test" as «class utf8»
set d to ""
repeat 50 times
    set d to d & linefeed
end repeat
set text item delimiters to d
text item 2 of input
```

Comment: Thats quit a neat idea :-)